# Pycharm scrolling vs SublimeText2 one

Tags: python, sublimetext2, pycharm, sublimetext3

I've recently migrated from SublimeText2 to the PyCharm IDE. Well it has some advantages and I have set it up in minimal style, turned many toolbars off and even moved my favorite color scheme to it.
So ST2 scrolling by mouse wheel or touchpad gesture (I use OS X) scrolls content pixel-by-pixel so I can scroll it even for one pixel if I want. It looks so smoothly and I like it.
However Pycharm scrolling scrolls content line-by-line and I do not like it. It looks ragged :(
The question is how can I made scrolling behavior the same as the ST2 one? :)

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand what you are trying to get at, I really do not feel a difference when scrolling in Pycharm and in Sublime Text 2. The difference you feel may be caused by not turning on the smooth scroll feature in PyCharm.

[image]

Comment: I think the difference might only be visible in OSX. Not sure as I haven't used Windows later than version 7. But in OSX you can normally scroll with pixel-level precision, which does not seem to be possible in PyCharm. This may sound trivial but if you are used to OSX scrolling behavior, you will probably feel that PyCharm behaves in an unresponsive, sluggish way - even if it is not.

Comment: @MagnusWolffelt I'm using OS X 10.11 and PyCharm 5.0.4. It allows for per-pixel smooth-scrolling, but the scrolling performance is terrible - if I drag the scrollbar fast I get what feels like 2-3fps - it only feels smooth if I scroll very slowly, it must be due to poor text rendering performance in whatever GUI toolset PyCharm is using.